# Can't make og:determiner work on Open graph object

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am trying to post an open graph action with one of my objects.

Everything works fine except that I need the 'a' article used with my object, so I added the og:determiner meta tag as described in the docs:

```
<meta property="og:determiner" content="a" />
```

But when I check the post on my timeline I see that the determiner is not used at all and the sentence comes out strange.

What might be wrong? am I missing some definition in the dev app?

Comment: Have you figure this out?  I am having the same issue.